# Is e^{-distance(. , .)} a valid kernel for any distance metric?

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces, positive-semidefinite, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

In other words, for a set of $n$ distinct points, with $d_{ij}$ being the distance between point $i$ and point $j$, is the $n \times n$ matrix $M = [e^{-d_{ij}}]$ positive semidefinite?

I've written some code to look for counterexamples and haven't found any, so I'm quite sure it's true, but I can't find a proof online.

So far, I've found some interesting facts about the matrix $M$, but I don't know if they lead anywhere.
$$M^2_{ij} \leq n M_{ij}$$
$$|M| = \hspace{-1.2cm} \sum_{g \in \textrm{directed graphs over $n$ points, where each point has out-degree and in-degree 1}} \hspace{-4cm} (-1)^{\textrm{# of loops with even # of points}} e^{-\textrm{sum of lengths of edges in }g}$$

Also, I think I can prove the result given a proof of the following:

For a bipartite graph, if you take the softmin over $(d_{ij})_{i \in [n], j \in [n], i \textrm{ and } j \textrm{ on same side}}$ that is bigger than the softmin over  $(d_{ij})_{i \in [n], j \in [n], i \textrm{ and } j \textrm{ on opposite sides}}$. (Note that distances between distinct points are being double-counted, but distances between a point and itself are not.)

Comment: No assumptions on the metric or the underlying set, i.e. the domain of definition of the metric? So for any metric space?

Comment: Suppose the $n$ points are all at distance $1$ from each other (for example, if they are the vertices of a complete graph). Then the column of $M$ are equal and $M$ cannot be positive definite (it has rank $1$).

Comment: @Didier No, because the distance of a point to itself has to be 0. So that would be a matrix with ones on the diagonal, and 1/e everywhere else.

Comment: @gg Right any metric space

Comment: @gg Yes it does, thank you!